# Extend the limit of background process in ios 10.3.2 and above versions

Tags: ios, background-process, location-services

I am working an application that is sending the device's location to server after every 15mins. The logic is inside **didUpdateToLocation** i am scheduling a timer to call method **restartLocationUpdates** after every 
 180secs(3mins)and stopping the location updates by calling **stopLocationDelayBy10Seconds** after 10 seconds to save battery.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
//some bussiness logic goes here....
if(sendLocation){
    //send location to server
}
UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
if([application respondsToSelector:@selector(beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)]){
    bgTaskId = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTaskId];
        bgTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    }];
//using a timer to schedule a method call
self.bgtimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:180 target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(restartLocationUpdates)
                                                           userInfo:nil
                                                            repeats:NO];

//stopping the locatioupdates after 10 seconds to save battery
self.delayTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self
                                                                    selector:@selector(stopLocationDelayBy10Seconds)
                                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                                     repeats:NO];
}

- (void) restartLocationUpdates {
counter++;
    if(counter == 5){
        sendLocation = YES;
        counter=0;
    }else{
       sendLocation = NO;
    }
  //invalidating the bgtimer before creating and scheduling it again.
  if (self.bgtimer) {
      [self.bgtimer invalidate];
      self.bgtimer = nil;
  }
//configuring location manager and then starting location updates
//.....
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)stopLocationDelayBy10Seconds{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Before ios10 it is working fine but after iOS10.3.2 the bgtimer 
    is not working consistently, it stops working after 10 mins as app goes 
    to background state. Can someone help me what is wrong with the code 
    and how to keep running the timer while app is in background.

Imp: Location Services permission is set to 'Always' & BackgroundMode
    is enable for location updates & Backgroundfetch